# Como verificar presença de determinados valores num array?

Tags: php, array

Tenho a variável `$search_dorms` que me retorna `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )`.

Ela pode retornar também `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )`

Ou simplesmente `Array ( [0] => 1 )`

Estou tentando verificar os valores retornados mas sem sucesso. Peço ajuda. O código que estou usando é:

```
if(in_array(array('1'), $search_dorms)) {

    $search_dorms = 1;
    echo $search_dorms . "<br><br>";    

} elseif (in_array(array('1', '2'), $search_dorms)){

    $search_dorms = 2;
    echo $search_dorms . "<br><br>";        

}
```

Como eu poderia verificar se os valores que podem ser strings ou números estão dentro do `array $search_dorms`? Se repararem, estou tentando verificar ***mais de 1 valor simultaneamente*** e é isso que tá pegando.

> Uma outra forma de explicar o que falei acima:

```
if(in_array(1, $search_dorms)) echo "Ok<br><br>";
if(in_array(array(1, 2), $search_dorms)) echo "Ok novamente<br><br>";
```

Estou tentando fazer esta verificação. O **"Ok novamente"** não aparece.

Comment: Se tivesse usado o radiobutton que eu recomendei, não teria esse problema. Seria só ver se é 1, 2 ou 3+ ...

Comment: @Bacco que legal que lembrou e se atentou que era pro mesmo projeto ... está atento ... rsrsrs ... radio button não dá porque pode ter multipla escolha.

Comment: O cara querer 1 dormitório ou 3+ e não querer 2? E é fácil ver que é o mesmo projeto, só de array vc tem umas ultimas 5 em seguida kkkk. Acho que vc tem que dar uma repensada na lógica de uso. Na verdade se o cara escolhe 2 dormitorios, é pq 1 só nao serve.

Comment: rsrsrsrs ... estou aprendendo e muito, muito mesmo com vocês ... levando broncas e puxões de orelha aqui, acabei por fazer esse projeto todo em PHPOO só com as dicas de vocês.

Comment: @Bacco é um pouco muito idiota pensar que o cara que marca 1 dormitório vai marcar 3 ou vice-versa mais o cliente quer assim .. paciência ...

Comment: Bom, se for assim, a gambiara é o de menos :) - Quero ver como é que vai fazer a query da busca depois. Vai ficar meio "enrolada".

Answer (score 5):

Dei uma olhada na documentação do in_array em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php e pelo que eu entendi o "ok novamente" nã está aparecendo pelo seguinte motivo:

```
in_array(array(1, 2), $search_dorms);
```

está procurando por um array que contenha os dois inteiros, 1 e 2, dentro do array $search_dorms e não uma procura do inteiro 1 e do inteiro 2 em $search_dorms.
Se você fizer assim:

```
var_dump(in_array(array(1, 2), $search_dorms));
```

verá que ele retornará bool(false) (O motivo de nao entrar no bloco if), porém se você fizer:

```
$search_dorms = array(1, 2, array(1,2));
$foo = array(1,2);
var_dump($foo, $search_dorms);
```

verá que retornará bool(true).

vale também lembrar que o terceiro parametro de in_array() verificar o tipos. assim:

```
$search_dorms = array(1, 2, 3);
$foo = '1';
var_dump(in_array($foo, $search_dorms, true));
```

retornará bool(false)

para resolver seu problema sugiro que coloque o operador && dentro do if.

```
if(in_array(1, $search_dorms) && in_array(2, $search_dorms)){...}
```

fontes: in_array(): http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php
var_dump(): http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Cara tu foi fundo buscar esta solução hein ... provavelmente vai funcionar pra mim ... vou fazer os testes ... parabéns !!!